# Why is the 'break' not working in this function?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following function that is intended to retry a `requests.post` call. It is working as written but I want the loop to stop once the command succeeds. Right now the function continues to loop even though the command is successful & I'm not sure why.

```
def retry_post(url, data, headers, max_retries=3):
  for retry in range(max_retries):
    try:
      response = requests.post(url, data, headers)
      if response.status_code == 200:
        break
      else:
        print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}. Retrying...")
    except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, Exception):
      print(f"Request failed with exception: {e}. Retrying...")
  if response.status_code != 200:
    raise RuntimeError("Max retries exceeded.")
  return response
```

Comment: I don't see how that is possible.  The loop should stop.  What actual behavior are you seeing that makes you think the `break` did not work?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the request is succeeding with a 200, and not some other success code, like perhaps a redirect?

Comment: As a very simple debugging step, you could add a `print()` message in the `if` block, above the `break` statement.

Comment: Potential error opportunity :  `NameError: name 'e' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed the request.post to data=data and headers=headers parameters in the requests.post call to have the function works correctly. Needed to add as e to raise the exception.

```
import requests

def retry_post(url, data, headers, max_retries=3):
    for retry in range(max_retries):
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                break
            else:
                print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}. Retrying...")
        except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, Exception) as e:
            print(f"Request failed with exception: {e}. Retrying...")

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise RuntimeError("Max retries exceeded.")
    
    return response
```